# C# Change int value of item in enum

Tags: c#, enums, setvalue

I have this enum

```
 enum Items { pen = 5, watch = 4, rubber = 1, ruler = 8};
```

and I want to change the value of watch (now is 4) to 6. So something like this:

```
Items.watch = 6;
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: And why would you want to do this? You can change it in the enum declaration directly, so setting 6 instead of 4. Changing it after it's assigned seems like a weird use case.

Comment: Enums are basically a collection of named constants thus reassigning the value is not possible.

Comment: The only way of doing that would be to recompile the assembly which declares `Items`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of an enum is fixed at compile time. According to [Microsoft's C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.

Note the term "constants". If you want to change the integer value of an enum entry, you must recompile the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change numeric values of enum constants, because they are, well, constant.

You can associate a separate value with an enum by setting up a dictionary, but that would not change the values of the enum constants themselves:

```
private static IDictionary<Items,int> AssociatedValue = new Dictionary<Items,int> {
    {Items.pen, 5}, {Items.watch, 4}, {Items.rubber, 1}, {Items.ruler, 8}
};
```

Now you can set

```
AssociatedValue[Items.watch] = 6
```

but you would have to use `AssociatedValue[enumVal]` in place of `(int)enumVal` when you need the integer value.